# AWS SES - Sending Emails

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I have created an SES Account and I have verifed my domain - easy as the A record is already with AWS route53. I now need to send emails. Note: I have also created an smtp user account and have the keys.

Question - can I use any (lets say PHP as I like PHP) php script to send emails via SES?

I have found a couple of sites that appear to have scripts for SES like http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/ but wanted to ask if now my domain is verified and I have user/keys etc is SES really just an SMTP gateway and I can use any (working) script to send emails via this interface?

thx

Comment: Don't forget to up vote or mark answers correct if they are helpful! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use their SMTP gateway or send emails via the AWS SDK for PHP programmatically. Just download the SDK, include it in your PHP file and you're good to go.

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/12/13/amazon-simple-email-service-gets-simpler-with-smtp/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#i=AmazonSES

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/